# Intel Fortran Compiler with large file size

Tags: fortran, fortran77, intel-fortran

I have a large piece of legacy code that is written in Fortran 77.  I am compiling it and running it with the Intel Fortran Compiler (Version 11?).  I recently ran into an issue where the output file reached just shy of 2GB in size, and the output stopped getting written to disk.

I have hunted around looking to see if this is part of the Fortran 77 standard, or if I am simply missing a compiler flag or something, but haven't found anything that points towards my problem.

Changing the write statements isn't an option, since the legacy code is on the order of several hundred thousand lines.  Worst case scenario is that every few days I go in and truncate the earlier portions of the output to a different file, but I would prefer that I not have to do this.

Comment: Successive Fortran standards scarcely recognise the existence of files (or computers for that matter) let alone set limits on them.  Standards note that this sort of thing, interaction with the environment, is implementation-specific.  I'm not aware that the Intel compiler, which I use heavily, sets limits on output file sizes.  Your specification of a 2GB upper limit makes me suspect that this is an o/s limit; are you perhaps running on a 32-bit Windows system ?

Comment: I am running on 64-bit Scientific Linux 6.3, which is a RedHat Clone.  I will check my file-system type to see if that can be the issue.  Edit: All my partitions are ext4, so that shouldn't be the issue either.

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 3):

The most probable reason for this kind of behaviour is the memory model in use. In 64-bit mode there are three memory models, distinguished by the addressing mode used:

- `small` model - `RIP`-related addressing is used for everything, from calling functions to accessing data. `RIP` is the 64-bit instruction pointer register of x64 (the 64-bit extension of `EIP`), but the relative address can only be a signed 32-bit number (and there are some restrictions that prevent the use of the full signed integer range), hence the combined code + static data size is limited to about 2 GiB.
- `medium` model - program code is limited to 2 GiB, hence `RIP`-related function calls, but data symbols are split in two types. Small data symbols are those that fit together with the code in the first 2 GiB and they are addressed using the same `RIP`-relative method as in the small model. Large data symbols are accessed using register addressing with the absolute address of the symbol loaded into a register, which is slower but there are no limits on the addressable memory.
- `large` model - all symbols are accessed using absolute addressing. There are no restrictions on the code or data size.

Most compilers that can target x64, `ifort` included, accept the `--mcmodel=model` option that allows one to control the memory model used. The default model is `small`. The size of your object file means that there is an enormous quantity of initialised static data, possibly some very large initialised arrays (think `DATA` or `BLOCK DATA` statements) or many smaller arrays (I doubt that even 1 million code statements would generate 2 GiB of instructions code). Compiling with `--mcmodel=medium` or `--mcmodel=large` should solve the problem with the large object file size.

Note that linking together object codes that use different memory models is a recipe for disaster - the whole application should be compiled with the same memory model.